# sql cross joins alternative

Tags: sql, performance

I need to know if there is a better/optimized way of writing this subquery from performance perspective. Actually its a question of implementing a better join I think.

```
SELECT SE.TOUCHPOINT_ID, SE.TOUCHPOINT_DATE,
       COALESCE(AC.COST_VAR_PER_SESSION, 0) + COALESCE(MC.COST_VAR_PER_SESSION, 0) AS COST_VAR_PER_SESSION,
       COALESCE(AC.COST_FIX_PER_SESSION, 0)  + COALESCE(MC.COST_FIX_PER_SESSION, 0) AS COST_FIX_PER_SESSION
FROM MLOGIC.ATTR.MARKETING_TOUCHPOINTS SE, MLOGIC.COST.AD_COST_DISTRIBUTION AC, MLOGIC.COST.SOURCE_MEDIUM_COST_DISTRIBUTION MC
WHERE SE.TOUCHPOINT_DATE = AC.TOUCHPOINT_DATE
   AND SE.AD_ID = AC.AD_ID
   AND SE.TOUCHPOINT_DATE = MC.TOUCHPOINT_DATE
   AND SE.MEDIUM_ID = MC.MEDIUM_ID
   AND SE.TOUCHPOINT_ID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM LEAD_EVENTS )
```

Comment: Which database are you targeting?

Comment: Replace the "not in (select * )" with some "not exists (select 1 from LEAD_EVENTS where xxxx=SE.TOUCHPOINT_ID)

Comment: For maintenance and reading reasons, I've got used to joins...
from mlogic.attr.marketing_touchpoints SE join mlogic.cost.ad_cost_distribution AC on SE.ad_id = AC.ad_id and SE.touchpoint_date = AC.touchpoint_date join mlogic.cost.source_medium_cost_distribution MC on SE.touchpoint_date = MC.touchpoint_date and SE.medium_id = MC.medium_id

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you use explicit `join` syntax.  But I don't really think that will change the performance of a modern db server.  Otherwise the `not exists` syntax typically performs a little better than `not in`.

Comment: Yes, do you have some indexes on that? And how selective is the `SE.TOUCHPOINT_ID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM LEAD_EVENTS )` predicate?

Comment: @pascal I don't know the database. Its a general question. yes not exists would help. But I think a more efficient join would be most helpful. other than the explicit join. No, info on indexes info at hand. not even the predicate.

Comment: If the references between the tables are what they seem from this query, I would not worry too much about the joins...

Comment: The question is too broad as it is. Optimizers, materialized views, clustered indexes, clusters... depending on your database; some estimation of the volumes... Too many parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Switching to proper `JOIN` syntax will probably not change the performance.  However, it will make the query more intelligible and maintainable.

On the other hand, switching the `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS` probably will improve performance.  So I would suggest:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM MLOGIC.ATTR.MARKETING_TOUCHPOINTS SE JOIN
     MLOGIC.COST.AD_COST_DISTRIBUTION AC
     ON SE.TOUCHPOINT_DATE = AC.TOUCHPOINT_DATE AND
        SE.AD_ID = AC.AD_ID JOIN
     MLOGIC.COST.SOURCE_MEDIUM_COST_DISTRIBUTION MC
     ON SE.TOUCHPOINT_DATE = MC.TOUCHPOINT_DATE AND
        SE.MEDIUM_ID = MC.MEDIUM_ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM LEAD_EVENTS LE
                  WHERE LE.TOUCHPOINT_ID = SE.TOUCHPOINT_ID   -- guessing on the name of the column
                 );
```

For this, you want an index on `LEAD_EVENTS(TOUCHPOINT_ID)`.